# Why my loop keep adding letters to a string and doesn't erase them afterwards?

Tags: python, string, list, loops

Right now I'm going to build a palindrome checker.

My idea was to set an empty list, then ask the user for a string, add all the letters to the string, reverse it and then create a new word by "sum" with the letters reversed. Afterwards, check if both words are the same. If they are the same, it's a bingo!

But somehow, after the first try, the "palindrome" value is not reset but, rather, it keeps storing the old word and adds the new word on top (Or right after) therefore making the program not properly check.

Here is my code:

```
USER_WORD_LETTERS = []

finished = False

while finished == False:
    USER_WORD = input("Write a word: ")
    palindrome = ''
        if USER_WORD == 'q':
            finished = True
        else:
            for i in USER_WORD:
                USER_WORD_LETTERS.append(i)
            USER_WORD_LETTERS.reverse()
            for i in USER_WORD_LETTERS:
                palindrome += i
            if palindrome == USER_WORD:
                print("Your word is a palindrome!")
            else:
                print("Your word is not a palindrome!")
```

So how do I avoid this? Is there a command or function to "erase" a string?

Comment: You need to define `USER_WORD_LETTERS` inside your while loop it seems like.  Otherwise, it keeps all of your entries.

Comment: Too check if a word is a palindrome: `word = "hobbit"; word == word[::-1]`

Comment: Yes! That did it. Also Simeon Aleksov method works as well and I now know a useful function for deleting content inside a list. Thanks guys!

Comment: also, instead of `for c in char_list: new_string += c` just use `new_string = "".join(char_list)`

Comment: And, it just doesn't make sense to add every character into a list in this case. If you were, you should use `my_list = list(my_string)`. But strings are sequences in Python, and you can manipulate them as such, just no mutation since they are immutable.

Comment: Thanks juanpa! Very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the list inside the `while` loop.

```
USER_WORD_LETTERS = []

finished = False

while finished == False:
    USER_WORD_LETTERS.clear()
    USER_WORD = input("Write a word: ")
    palindrome = ''
    if USER_WORD == 'q':
        finished = True
    else:
        for i in USER_WORD:
            USER_WORD_LETTERS.append(i)
        USER_WORD_LETTERS.reverse()
        for i in USER_WORD_LETTERS:
            palindrome += i
        if palindrome == USER_WORD:
            print("Your word is a palindrome!")
        else:
            print("Your word is not a palindrome!")
```